# Laravel query builder for Charts.js

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, chart.js

I have logic querying a MSSQL Server database view and I've been searching for a solutions along with trying different techniques. Of course I don't expect a full solution where this is two parts (query builder & frontend javascript/chart) but any helpful direction would greatly appreciated. Here I'm getting the count of Leads on a particular day grouped by the date created and source of the leads. I'm trying build this the Laravel way so to speak, and display in charts.js. I'm thinking I might need to make two different database calls/queries. One count and one for the group by source text.

Thank you for your help for a solutions or an helpful direction I can take.

I have already done total leads for another chart but this project has some extra sugar to it.

```
SELECT count([LeadID]) as numleads,[LeadSource],cast(leadcreated as date) as 
  `enter code here`createddate 
  FROM [myDatabase].[dbo].[viewAllLeads]
  where companyid=001
  group by cast(leadcreated as date),[LeadSource]
  order by createddate
```

Chart.js set up:
- Top links (horizontal) the groupby info by LeadSource
- Left, y-axis - the count of the leads
- Bottom x-axis - the date lead was created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should actually be straight forward, but you need to be aware that using `DB::raw()` is necessary. To begin with, here your query a little bit nicer formatted:

```
SELECT
  [LeadSource],
  CAST([leadcreated] as date) as createddate,
  COUNT([LeadID]) as numleads
FROM [dbo].[viewAllLeads]
WHERE [companyid] = '001'
GROUP BY [LeadSource], CAST([leadcreated] as date)
ORDER BY [createddate]
```

And converted to an Eloquent query:

```
DB::table('viewAllLeads') // the query builder doesn't care if it's a table or view
    ->select([
        'LeadSource',
        DB::raw('CAST(leadcreated as date) as createddate'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(LeadID) as numleads')
    ])
    ->where('companyid', '001')
    ->groupBy('LeadSource', DB::raw('CAST(leadcreated as date)'))
    ->orderBy('createddate')
    ->get();
```

This will return a `Illuminate\Support\Collection` containing `stdClass` objects of the following form:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["LeadSource"] => string(3) "ABC"
  ["createddate"] => string(10) "2019-08-05"
  ["numleads"] => int(15)
}
```

Comment: Yes!!! Please excuse the small excitement. LOL. Greatly appreciated! This worked! Now, to work on the front end for charts. Thanks again!

Comment: @EdwardGüereque If the answer solved your problem, please accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, the check symbol under the voting arrows in the left top corner of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$leads = Lead::where('companyid', $companyid)->get()->groupBy(function ($item) {
    return $item->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
})->sortBy(function ($item) {
    return $item->created_at->format('x');
});
```

if you use `dd($leads)` you can see the data structure.

Comment: That's going to group in-memory, not the best idea performance-wise.